# Why the constraints in optimization problems are preferred to be convex?

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, machine-learning, non-convex-optimization

Specifically in SVM, it is preferred to have a convex constraint. The preference given to a convex optimization objective is straight-away understandable (to ensure convergence at a global optimum), but it is not quite clear to me why constraints should also be convex.

For eg, in SVM the parameters (weights to the separating hyperplane) are not preferred to be on the surface of a hypersphere. Why?

I read at many places that a non-convex constraint may cause ending up at a local mimima, how is that possible if the objective function is itself convex?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

A convex function over a nonconvex domain may have non-global local minima. Just consider to minimize $f(x,y)=x^2 +x +y^2/2$ over the unit circle; you get one non-global minimum.

Comment: That is my doubt, how can a convex function end up at a local minimum (since the convex function has only one point of minima).

Comment: I have an example. Try to work it out and you will see.

Comment: I worked out the example, found that the point is not the point of global minimum of f. Can you please give some general explanation, or direct me to some resources where I can study this? I searched a lot, but could not find an exhaustive explanation. Thank you.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean... If you do some descent algorithm on the constraint problem I gave, you may end up in the non-global minimum. (Oh, and another thing: a convex function can have more than a single minimizer - the set of minimizers can be any convex set.)

Comment: Guess I got it.. Thank you!

Comment: Even if the domain is convex, it needs to be defined by convex functions.

Comment: @Dirk But what is the problem? Since we work with a constraint nothing guarantees us that we get the global minimum. But this could happen also if we had a convex constraint.

Comment: For a convex function over a convex domain each local minimum is global.